# Options for library and or program for OSX / Windows GUI builder in C, C#, or Java

Tags: c#, c, forms, user-interface, cross-platform

I am developing a Map editing software that works in correlation with my Android game engine. I currently have the software nearly complete written in c# using visual studios. You can view the required functionality and current program via this video [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75TDw2DCjY8).

I realize after already developing the map editor that visual studios was not the best choice for me. I need the engine to run on OSX AND Windows (linux would be nice too). What I am asking from you is what are some decent options for building a cross platform GUI. I have done some research on QT however I am not a huge fan of C++. I would prefer to write in C, C#, Java, or possibly a scripting language.

Here is a list of things I would like to see:

- Cross platform ( OSX and Windows are a must)
- Visual Form builder (I like QTs and Visual Studios...also not that picky)
- GUI is clean (Design is big for me, so I dont want the old windows 2000 look)
- Not C++

I understand Java in itself is cross platform; however, it seems clunky to me. Thats more of a last resort.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The mono framework is an open source version of the dot net framework that works on Linux and Mac

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page